# looping in knitr through captions and graphs

Tags: r, graph, r-markdown, knitr, caption

Suppose i have to following dataset :

`data.frame(group=paste0("group",c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4),rep(3,4))),caption=c(paste0("caption",1:12)),png_file=c(paste0("graph",1:12,".png")))`

That look like this:

```
group   caption    png_file
1  group1  caption1  graph1.png
2  group1  caption2  graph2.png
3  group1  caption3  graph3.png
4  group1  caption4  graph4.png
5  group2  caption5  graph5.png
6  group2  caption6  graph6.png
7  group2  caption7  graph7.png
8  group2  caption8  graph8.png
9  group3  caption9  graph9.png
10 group3 caption10 graph10.png
11 group3 caption11 graph11.png
12 group3 caption12 graph12.png
```

Suppose from it, i want to have sections corresponding to groups, and one empty subsection for each graph, with a knitr::include_graphics() with the right caption.

For the first ones, i'll write something like that in my markdown :

````
# group1

##

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="caption1"}
knitr::include_graphics("graph1.png")
```

##

```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="caption2"}
knitr::include_graphics("graph2.png")
```
````

and so on.

How can i automate this process ?? I strugle writing a loop with r chunks insisde...

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a-OK?

````
```{r, results='asis'}
cat(sprintf('![%s](%s)', df$caption, df$png_file), sep = '\n')
```
````

Comment: Ok i tried to use the ![]() classical markdown format. Why the print(noquote()) ? It helps but i still cant make it work

Comment: You need print in the loop otherwise it won't show, the noquote is to remove the string quotes. Check if you can make it work outside a loop.

Comment: Even without the loop, i'm not able to make it plot something. In my html page, i have a tag :

<embed data-src="%22my_file.png%22">

And th'ats all i'm getting

Comment: I would suggest you try to make it work first, try it outside of a chunk, see if the problem lies in the chunk. Sometimes this syntax can have problems not finding images.

Comment: The issue in you code was the "" around the file name. Now it works. Thank's !!

Comment: The `for` loop could be vectorized (which makes the code more compact). I hope you don't mind me revising your code.

Comment: As I find rMarkdown and now Quarto - at least on Windowns - have some issues if there are no blank lines **between** paragraphs, I would edit to:

```cat(sprintf('![%s](%s)\n', df$caption, df$png_file), sep = '\n')```
Notice the extra `\n` at the end of the sprintf.

Without this change, no captions except the one applied to the very last one in the list will render. This applies if i have `fig-cap-location: bottom' in my yaml. I have tested this both with a R Markdown and a Quarto document.